# Is it safe to protect SQL Database (.mdf) by checking the last modified date?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I want to protect the SQL Database (.mdf) file by checking if the last modified date of the database file matches my Application's record. So that if user edit any data from the database it can be identified. So is it safe to use this method? Or is there any better method?

> Please don't suggest store .mdf file on different machine and access it by using LAN connection.

Comment: Protecting from whom, exactly?

Comment: From the operator. Maybe he could learn to edit SQL DB Files.

Answer (score 1):

The database file modified date does not change when a user performs an update or delete according to this link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b7db6744-cd7b-42b5-a84e-5e511a5e8e59/mdf-ldf-files-last-modified-date-not-increasing-as-expected?forum=sqldisasterrecovery

What are you concerned about? Are you concerned about a DBA making modifications or an application user making modifications? If you want to know what users are doing then could you create a table called dbAudit, which contains four fields i.e. ID (Primary Key), Username, datecreated and sqlquery.  You could log all of the sql queries run against the database by the application.

It may also be worth looking into Transparent Data Encryption: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/transparent-data-encryption-tde

Comment: Thanks for your very helpful reply. So according to you protecting db file using GetLastWriteTime isn't a good practice, right? So can briefly tell me more about Transparent Data Encryption? I am searching but since you may already know about this your help would be very much helpful to me.

Comment: Have a read of the link posted in the question.  What are you concerned about? e.g. someone accessing data that they shouldn't; someone deleting the .mdf file etc?

Comment: Sorry for late. I am fearing someone could open the mdf file from SQL Server Management Studio or Visual Studio or some other similar applications which can edit mdf file data. So if they do so then I want to detect it when they open that database in my application.

Comment: You need to look into security. Security of the server where database is stored and internal database security.

Comment: @alex Actually it is actually stored in the same computer

Comment: @John Khan, in windows restrict users who can access MDF file to yourself, sql server and any other SQL relates services you may be running (e.g. Job agent).